# Convert Int to hexadecimal in form of bytes object

Tags: python-3.x, hex, byte

I am trying to convert an integer to hexadecimal but I want it to be in bytes object. for example:
input: 62353
output: b'f391'

Comment: hex(62353) returns a string. I need it to be bytes

Comment: `bytes.fromhex(f'{62353:x}')` or `int(62353).to_bytes(length=2, byteorder='big')`.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Why did you add f before '{62353:x}' because python 3.5 does not support a 'F' prefix

Comment: true (the question is not tagged with python-3.5, though...). there it would be: `'{:x}'.format(62353)`.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by using int(62353).to_bytes(length=2, byteorder='big')